# How long does it take for a new org to be published on salesforce's dns?

Tags: trailhead, developer-edition, developer-org

I'm doing a few trailheads and created a new org, but when I try to link the org to my trailhead account I keep getting

> Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce administrator.

I've seen this before and its because the url to login at first creating it uses the server number. Ie cs17.salesforce.com, but linking an org to trailhead uses login.salesforce.com

Does anyone know how long it takes for new orgs to be published under login.salesforce.com?

Comment: You gave `cs17.salesforce.com` as the server number. That's a sandbox org. You cannot link sandboxes to Trailhead, only Developer Edition orgs or "playground" orgs created inside Trailhead.

Comment: The premise is that same, @charles t. I cannot login into my newly created org through login.salesforce.com.